# Unity Invoke Returning a Value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, return-value, invoke

I have a C# method (for Unity) below:

```
int CheckLength()
{
    Collider[] enemies = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, transform.localScale.x);
    return enemies.Length;
}
```

I want to use this metod with some delay, so I must use Invoke() method. But the problem is I cannot get the return value of the method, because Invoke() method's return type is void. How can I use this method with some delay and get the return value?

Comment: There are many ways of [How to delay code in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189432/how-to-delay-a-method-in-unity-and-c/58189532#58189532) .. your best option is probably [How to return a value from a Coroutine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267537/unity-need-to-return-value-only-after-coroutine-finishes)

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you use [Invoke()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html), then there **won't be a return value** until the code actually executes, long after the method that called `Invoke()` in the first place has returned. If you want the return value, don't use `Invoke()`. Why are you using `Invoke()` here in the first place? What benefit is there to delaying this call? Please improve the question so that it makes some sense.

Comment: @PeterDuniho My goal is, delaying this function and getting its value. But as you said, Invoke() won't return a value. I should use this function in Update() method. In my opinion, using a coroutine in Update() method is unsuitable.

Comment: @ThyRety Why? Coroutines are used in `Update` and `FixedUpdate` all the time. If you don't want to go that route for whatever reason, `async`/`await` is another option.

Comment: @3Dave Okay, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Could you maybe give us a clear use case? **Why** do you need this with a delay? How exactly are you going to use it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to get a "returned" value after a delay.

One of them is to give a coroutine an Action with a parameter as a "return to" or more accurately not return to but continue with.

```
using System;
```

.

```
void Start(){
    StartCoroutine(Return5AfterDelay(
        (returnedValue)=>{
            // after
            print(returnedValue);
            
        }
    ));
}

IEnumerator Return5AfterDelay(flood delay, Action<int> continueWith){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay); 
    continueWith(5);
}
```